# How to print order by order id in magento sale order history

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, history

This is my code in history.phtml page

```
 <?php if($_orders->getSize()): ?>
 <?php $printurl = $this->getPrintUrl(); ?>
<table width="100%" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="3" border="0" align="center" class="order">
    <tbody>
        <tr bgcolor="#FF9800">
            <td align="left" style="width=100">
            <font size="2" face="Tahoma, Verdana" color="#FFFFFF"><b>Order #</b></font>
            </td>
            <td align="left" style="width=100">
            <font size="2" face="Tahoma, Verdana" color="#FFFFFF"><b>Amount</b></font>
            </td>
            <td align="left" style="width=100">
            <font size="2" face="Tahoma, Verdana" color="#FFFFFF"><b>Date of Order</b></font>
            </td>
            <td align="left" style="width=100">
            <font size="2" face="Tahoma, Verdana" color="#FFFFFF"><b>First Name </b></font>
            </td>
            <td align="left" style="width=100">
            <font size="2" face="Tahoma, Verdana" color="#FFFFFF"><b>Last Name </b></font>
            </td>
            <td align="left" style="width=100">
            <font size="2" face="Tahoma, Verdana" color="#FFFFFF"><b>Status</b></font>
            </td>
            <td align="left" style="width=100">
            <font size="2" face="Tahoma, Verdana" color="#FFFFFF"><b>Processed</b></font>
            </td>
            <td align="left" style="width=100">
            <font size="2" face="Tahoma, Verdana" color="#FFFFFF"><b>Print</b></font>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php $_odd = ''; ?>
        <?php foreach ($_orders as $_order): ?>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" align="left" class="margin-top-1 margin-bottom-1" width:30%="">
            <font size="2" face="Tahoma, Verdana">
            <?php echo $_order->getRealOrderId() ?></font>
            </td>
            <td valign="top" align="left" class="margin-top-1 margin-bottom-1" width:30%="">
            <font size="2" face="Tahoma, Verdana"><?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_order->getGrandTotal()) ?></font>
            </td>
            <td valign="top" align="left" class="margin-top-1 margin-bottom-1" width:30%="">
            <font size="2" face="Tahoma, Verdana"><?php echo $this->formatDate($_order->getCreatedAtStoreDate()) ?></font>
            </td>
            <td valign="top" align="left" class="margin-top-1 margin-bottom-1" width:30%="">
            <font size="2" face="Tahoma, Verdana">
            <?php echo $_order->getShippingAddress() ? $this->htmlEscape($_order->getShippingAddress()->getFirstname()) : '&nbsp;' ?>
            </font>
            </td>
            <td valign="top" align="left" class="margin-top-1 margin-bottom-1" width:30%="">
            <font size="2" face="Tahoma, Verdana">
            <?php echo $_order->getShippingAddress() ? $this->htmlEscape($_order->getShippingAddress()->getLastname()) : '&nbsp;' ?>
            </font>
            </td>
            <td valign="top" align="left" class="margin-top-1 margin-bottom-1" width:30%="">
            <font size="2" face="Tahoma, Verdana"><?php echo $_order->getStatusLabel() ?></font>
            </td>
            <td valign="top" align="left" class="margin-top-1 margin-bottom-1" width:30%="">
            <font size="2" face="Tahoma, Verdana"> 
            <?php //echo $_order->getStatus(); ?>
             </font>
            </td>
            <td valign="top" align="left" class="margin-top-1 margin-bottom-1" width:30%="">
            <font size="2" face="Tahoma, Verdana"><a class="blueColor" onclick="window.open('<?php echo $printurl;?>','printer_friendly','toolbar=0,location=0,status=0,menubar=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,width=640,height=390')">Print</a></font>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php else : ?>
<p>No order history found !.</p>
<?php endif ?>
```

The `$printurl` is something like :

```
http://mysite.com/index.php/sales/order/print/order_id/104/
```

But now the $printurl not have any value.....

How can i do this?

Comment: I can tell the template file from your description. Which block class are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You ca use instead of `<?php $printurl = $this->getPrintUrl(); ?>` this

```
<?php $printurl = Mage::getUrl('sales/order/print', array('order_id',$_order->getId() )); ?>
```

inside the `foreach ($_orders as $_order)` loop

Answer (score 0):

Marius is right, but the correct version is:

```
<?php $printurl = Mage::getUrl('sales/order/print', array('order_id' => $_order->getId() )); ?>
```